# Clear Float with SASS mixin

Tags: css, sass, clearfix

I am getting an error with this

```
@mixin clear-fix($where) {
  &:{$where} {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "  &:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was "{$where} {" on line 2 of assets/src/sass/_setup.scss

I want to just be able to declare `after` or `before` and just drop it in the class i want it with just like

```
.container {
   max-width: 1200px;
   width: 100%;

   @include clear-fix('after');
}
```

For reference: [SASS Documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#sass-script-strings)

Comment: Double check your syntax.  You're missing a `#`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code fixed: (you can test in this tool http://sassmeister.com/)

```
@mixin clear-fix($where) {
  &:#{$where} {
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
  }
} 

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;

  @include clear-fix('after');
}
```